# REST with Jersey 1.x using interfaces. How to

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have designed the needed REST Service with JERSEY 1.5, using declared interface like:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public IMyDTO doIt(ICustomer customer) {
    return MySupport.createDTO(customer);
}
```

If i trying to call this service, using JERSEY 1.5 Client API, the following error occured:

*Can not construct instance of test.ICustomer, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information*

Currently i specify such parameter by client:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, 
                                                               Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
WebResource webResource = client.resource(restResource);
ClientResponse response = webResource.path(restResourcePath)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, customer);
if (response != null) {
if (response.hasEntity()) {
result = response.getEntity(IMytDTO.class);
}
....
```

.
The *ICustomer* and *IMyDTO*  are **java interfaces without** any jackson annotation. The implementations have no jackson annotations too.

My Question: how to (de) serialize the objects , if REST Service (Client) are used?

I would not change the java interfaces and use the implementations on service and client side...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to use a concrete class instead of an abstract class, I think you'll have to create a custom serializer and deserializer. A Jackson example is at:

http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/06/05/writing-a-custom-jackson-serializer-and-deserializer/

Comment: how to register that custom (de) serializer on JERSEY?

Comment: You should be able to configure Jersey to use Jackson in the spring config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883287/how-to-easily-use-jackson-for-jersey