# Converting JSON reponse to Java Object using REST API

Tags: rest

I want to convert JSON to java 
my json

```
var eateryRatingFactory = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.dineInMenu = [{
    header: "Food",
    items: [{
      name: "Quality",
      id: '1',
      rating: '0'
    },.....so on ]
  },......so on ];
self.deliveryMenu = //some values same as beloew
};
```

my java class

```
    public class EateryRatingAdapter {

    public List<Ratings> dineInMenu;
    public List<Ratings> deliveryMenu;
    //setters and getters   

    public class Ratings{
        public String header;
        public List<Item> items;
        //setters and getters
        public class Item{
            public String name;
            public String id;
            public String rating;
            //setters and getters
        }
    }

}
```

while i'm getting the JSON at Request body , it is giving 400 bad request mean syntax mistake can u guys help this out

Comment: Question already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426642/convert-json-to-pojo

Comment: Use Gson library for that

Answer (score 0):

Use Object Mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Your JSON should cater your class

String jsonString = "{"header": "Food"  , ................}"; 

//JSON from String to Object

**Ratings obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Ratings.class)**
```