# Java Class to Json (naming classes)

Tags: java, json, serialization

This is the example of data which contains around 100,000 objects approx.

```
{"data":
    {"1":
        {"1":
            {"value":"something"},
        "2":
            {"value":"something"}
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting above data in Java, currently I am using JSONObject to store these and return to JavaScript for display. 
Now what I want to do is to use Java classes instead of JSONObjects to save memory footprint on whole system as the number of objects can be more than 12 million which is basically 12 million hash objects to store POJOs.

**Problem** How to create class structure for dynamic names so that when I use Gson to convert classes to JSONObject it gives something like above sample data. Specifically the names 1,2,... n.
If possible, please leave a comment if you don't like or understand or the question is wrong.

Comment: This problem can be solved by parsing into a `Map<String, SomeObject>`. Besides that, your json is invalid, so I can't really help you with the perfect POJO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON to POJO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426642/convert-json-to-pojo)

Comment: @nbokmans sorry about that, fixed it. If I use Map, will it not be similar to use JSONObjects

Comment: I think I misread your question. What do you want to do? Currently, your system works on `JSONObject` and you want to move to POJO's? Or the other way around?

Comment: JSONObject to POJO @nbokmans